# C++ Memory Allocation new[] and delete[]

Tags: c++, memory, allocation

I'm trying to dynamically allocate a new object.

```
  int len = (nm == NULL) ? 0 : strlen(nm);

try {
  name = new char[len + 1];
}
catch(std::bad_alloc) {
  name = NULL;
}
if(name) {
    if(nm == NULL)
        strcpy(name, "");
    else
    {
        strcpy(name, nm);
        cmds=new command [num_of_cmds];
```

Then my destructor has them being deleted via

```
robot::~robot()
{
if (name) {
    delete[] name;
}
delete [] cmds;
}
```

I keep getting segementation faults, if i edit some code to initialize a value on a simple int, it breaks. My delete[] cmds breaks so i have to comment it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I will clarify more things if people need.

Comment: Post a small self compilable example which demonstrates your problem.Note that looking at your code, there is a lot to improve in it.Also, this example as is won't even compile I suspect this is a *made up* code not *the original* code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I saw this code two days ago.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10001614/c-vector-arrays-in-copy-constructors

Comment: @amit: Though the code is completely disastrous I don't see `cmds` being declared anywhere.I only see it being allocated, that doesn't tell if it is a member or not.

Comment: @Als: the code was editted [during the 5 minutes edit window] since the comment was written and is irrelevant now, I'll delete it.

Comment: How is name and cmds declared?

Comment: Save yourself from a world of pain and just use `std::string`.

Comment: Yep, use `std::string` and `std::vector` instead of that poor C++ arrays...

Comment: @dreamlax +1; Amen to that. Dealing with manually allocated arrays is just a disaster waiting to happen, no matter how careful you are it can sneak up on you. That's why most languages have a strong tested solution, some even make strings fun to work with (NSString with Obj-C/Cocoa). std::string is the C++ beauty integrated for dealing with character arrays (and C++11 has some neat stuff coming to that department in the future). std::vector is simply indispensible in the toolset of a C++ programmer when contemplating general arrays. Dynamic, templated, safe and beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

When your robot' name is NULL (`nm == NULL`), you alloc an empty string, but **don't** alloc `cmds`. So you should at least set cmds to NULL in that branch, or check in destructor `if (name && *name != 0)` before `delete [] cmds;`. I'd go with the first option...

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a *very* good reason not to, you should avoid using `new[]` and `delete[]` and instead use `std::string` and `std::vector`. These handle memory management for you; and are considerable easier to use because of that.

`std::vector` is far more useful than a manually allocated buffer, not only because it handles memory for you, but it is still compatible with older C-style APIs. In situations where you need to provide a `const char *` or `char *`, you can simply provide `&vec[0]` (as in, the address of the first element of the `std::vector`).

`std::string` makes memory management, string manipulation, and (in conjunction with `std::stringstream`) string formatting much, much, *much* easier. Don't be tempted to deal with memory management yourself, use the well-tested `std::string` and `std::vector`.

Comment: This is not answering the initial question but should considered, this is a case where there is really no need for manual memory allocation